# Como modificar la fecha minima de un datepicker al seleccionar otro datepicker?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-datepicker

pues eso, para un ERP para pedir vacaciones tengo dos datepickers de jquery pero cuando elijo la primera fecha en el segundo me permite poner una fecha anterior y la verdad es que no se como se puede limitar el minimo del otro. yo php lo que quieras pero Js la verdad se me hace bola. pido vuestra ayuda en este tema adjunto el codigo de js.

```js
            var disableddates = ["3-1-2019","3-19-2019", "4-5-2019", "4-18-2019", "4-19-2019", "4-22-2019", "5-1-2019", "5-3-2019", "6-7-2019", "7-5-2019", "7-25-2019", "7-31-2019", "8-2-2019", "8-15-2019", "9-6-2019", "10-4-2019", "10-12-2019", "11-1-2019", "12-6-2019", "12-25-2019"];
            function DisableSpecificDates(date) {
                var m = date.getMonth();
                var d = date.getDate();
                var y = date.getFullYear();
                var currentdate = (m + 1) + '-' + d + '-' + y ;
                for (var i = 0; i < disableddates.length; i++) {
                    if ($.inArray(currentdate, disableddates) != -1 ) {
                        return [false];
                    } 
                }
                var weekenddate = $.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
                return weekenddate; 
            }
            $(function() {
                $("#date_ex,#date_ex2").datepicker({
                    minDate: new Date(),
                    beforeShowDay: DisableSpecificDates,
                });
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es engancharte al evento `change` que dispara el primer datepicker (no olvidemos que no deja de ser un input) y, en base a eso, setear una nueva fecha de inicio en el segundo input, te dejo el [enlace](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate) a la API de jqueryUI donde se especifica esto.

Como tu código es en jQuery, mantendré esto para que no andemos diferenciando en cómo hacerlo en nativo o con jQuery.

Te dejo un pequeño ejemplo.

```js
jQuery('#startDate, #endDate').datepicker({
  minDate: new Date(),
});

jQuery(document).on('change', '#startDate', (event) => {
    const element = event.target;
    console.log(element.value);
    jQuery('#endDate').datepicker('option', 'minDate', element.value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/ui-darkness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<label for="startDate">
<input id="startDate" name="startDate">

<label for="endDate">
<input id="endDate" name="endDate">
```